# Ruby: uninitialized constant Logger::Warn

Tags: ruby, logging, configatron

I'm using Logger through config and this line:

```
configatron.log.level = Logger::Warn
```

gives me the error:

```
`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Logger::Warn (NameError)
```

Even if I require 'logger' at the top.

what gives?

< Ruby N00B >

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capitalization matters.  It should be `Logger::WARN`.